# Can't scroll page up/down with Owl Carousel 2

Tags: carousel, owl-carousel

I can't scroll page on mobile while start draggin on carousel. So if carousel take all visible space on mobile - it's become little bit tricky to go up/down to page...

How I can disable this kinda "interception" of scrolling?

Answer (score 9):

Add this CSS to your CSS/SASS file and this should work, it worked for me.

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage, .owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item {
-ms-touch-action: auto;
    touch-action: auto;
```

}

Answer (score 6):

`touch-action: auto;` don't work for me i use `touch-action:pan-y;` and it's work

add this css:

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage, .owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item {
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y !important;
    touch-action: pan-y !important;
}
```